# Problemas com função de transformação de data

Tags: php, html5, php-7

```html
$data              = $_POST["data"]; 

// Recebe a variável com a data, e cria um objeto DateTime a partir do formato especificado.
$objetoData = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);

// Reformata a data do jeito desejado
$data = $objetoData->format('Y-d-m');
```

To essa função aonde a mesma faz a troca data para o formato que eu desejo. Exemplo a data entra como 12/13/2018 e quando passa pela função sair 2018-12-13.

O problema e que a funçao só esta funcionado para datas antiga usando o exemplo acima só funciona do dia 12 pra trás do dia 13 q o atual ele mostra outra data que seria 2019-12-01.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos analisar seu código:

```
$data = "12/13/2018";
$objetoData = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
```

Na variável `$data` você tem 3 pedaços da string `12`, `13`e `2018`separados por barra. No objeto `DateTime` você configura o `format` em `d`, `m` e `Y`separados por barra. Isso significa que:

```
d = 12
m = 13 (mês que não existe)
Y = 2018
```

Logo, por padrão, o objeto foi criado para o início do mês de 2019, pois o ano que foi informado era de 2018. Por isso que ele funciona até 12.

**Solução:**

Você pode alterar o `format` para `m/d/Y` ou você pode alterar a data para `"13/12/2018"`. Precisa ver o que é melhor para o seu algorítimo.

Ficaria assim por exemplo:

```
$objetoData = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $data);
```